# Why does the charge on a charged metal sphere decrease when different sites on the sphere are measured?

Tags: electromagnetism

In our experiment the metal sphere was charged to 3000v and when measured with a proof plane was positively charged. 2 subsequent readings (both discharged between) on different parts of the sphere were found to be slightly decreased (but still positively charged).

Shouldn't the entire sphere be equally charged to 3000v so when measured shouldn't all readings be the same? What's causing the subsequent readings of the sphere to increase in the number of electrons?

Comment: Perhaps the metal sphere is not a perfect sphere. And there is measurement error

Comment: Is the power supply connected to the sphere whilst the proof plate touches the sphere?

Answer (score 2):

Posibble things I could think of:

- Measurement error
- Have you checked what happens as you switch back and forth between sides? Maybe the sphere is just continually losing charge
- The sphere isn't symmetric. Charges would be more concentrated near the 'sharper' end
- I'm not sure how a "proof plane" works but if you are touching the sphere the answer is obvious: You are taking away charges every time
  you touch it.